# WP8 Take Photo of Map

Tags: c#, dictionary, windows-phone-8

I have a Map control on one of my pages and I wish to take a picture of it and display it on a different screen. Does anyone know how I can achieve this? The map is within a `<Grid>`.

Answer (score 5, accepted):

You should use the `Render` method fo the `WriteableBitmap` class:

```
var writeableBitmap = new WriteableBitmap(desiredWidth, desiredHeight);

writeableBitmap.Render(mapControl, null);
writeableBitmap.Invalidate();

image.Source = writeableBitmap;
```

[MSDN Link](http://msdn.microsoft.com/fr-fr/library/system.windows.media.imaging.writeablebitmap.render%28v=vs.95%29.aspx)

Comment: Is your nick name "The Man" ? I am just curious?

Comment: @AMR what? what do you mean?

Comment: lol nm I was being sarcastic. I was just trying to illustrate that you came up with a great answer for a platform that doesn't have many experienced developers.

Comment: Very nice! Thank you very much Olivier. I have actually solved the issue using Google's static maps. But I shall definitely check this out too!